# Problema Phyton al actualizar un label en una ventana

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

soy un princinpiante en la programación en Python.

De momento lo máximo que he profundizado es el `tkinter` y el uso del `customtkinter`, para la creación de interfaces gráficas. Pero mi asunto es el siguiente:

```
#------ Uso de customtkinter  ------#

from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
from time import strftime

#---------  Crear ventana  -------------#

root=ctk.CTk()
root.title("Customtkinter")
root.geometry("400x300")

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
#ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")



#--------Anadir una ventana dentro de otra ventana-----------#

ventana=ctk.CTkFrame(master=root)            
ventana.pack(padx=15,pady=10,fill="both",expand=True)


#-------------Añadir reloj en la ventana---------------#

#Definicón de función para el control e interpretación del tiempo
def tiempo():
    stringt = strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
    labelt.config(text=stringt)
    labelt.after(1000, tiempo)


def fecha():
    stringf = strftime('%b %d %Y')
    labelf.config(text=stringf)
    labelf.after(1000, fecha)


#Label del reloj y fecha
labelt = ctk.CTkLabel(master=ventana, font=('aerial',15),text_color='white')   #Datos del eqiquetado de control
labelf = ctk.CTkLabel(master=ventana, font=('aerial',25),text_color='white')   #Datos del eqiquetado de control


labelf.pack(anchor='center')
fecha()
labelt.pack(anchor='center')
tiempo()


root.mainloop()
```

El asunto es que por separado, en una ventana con solo el código del reloj la funciona, pero cuando trato de hacer que este se actualice como un frame dentro de otra ventana no me detecta parte de la función para la fecha o tiempo con el uso de `after`.

Si alguien me ayudar a entender un poco esa parte se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el problema despues de una tarde, de igual manera gracias a todas aquellas personas que vieron la publicación. En todo caso espero que pueda servir de ayuda mi problema.

Fue un error de principiante, debido a que al no ver los argumentos que maneja la libreria `customtkinter`. Entre los principales fallos se encontraba el como se definia `config` para el dato strig y así hacer que este cambiara. Para `customtkinter` esto es mediante `configure`. Anexo como es que sería esto mediante el código completo.

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
#from customtkinter import CTkFrame, CTkLabel, CTk, set_appearance_mode
from time import strftime

#---------  Crear ventana  -------------#

root=ctk.CTk()
root.title("Customtkinter")
root.geometry("400x300")

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
#ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")



#--------Anadir una ventana dentro de otra ventana-----------#

ventana=ctk.CTkFrame(master=root)            
ventana.pack(padx=15,pady=10,fill="both",expand=True)


#-------------Añadir reloj en la ventana---------------#


def tiempo():
    stringt = strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
    labelt.configure(text=stringt)
    labelt.after(1000, tiempo)


def fecha():
    stringf = strftime('%b %d %Y')
    labelf.configure(text=stringf)
    labelf.after(1000, fecha)


#Label del reloj y fecha
labelt = ctk.CTkLabel(master=ventana, font=('aerial',15))   
labelf = ctk.CTkLabel(master=ventana, font=('aerial',25))  


labelf.pack(anchor='center')
fecha()
labelt.pack(anchor='center')
tiempo()

root.mainloop()
```